# Adding matching parentheses in vim (and skip if user re-types closing paren)

Tags: vim

I have the following mapping to add in matching parentheses in vim:

```
inoremap (  <C-o>:call InsertCharPair('(')<CR>

" Matching braces and such
function InsertCharPair(char)
    let char_at_pos = getline(".")[col(".")-1]
    let matching_char = {'[': ']', '{': '}', '(': ')', '"': '"', "'": "'"}
    if char_at_pos =~ '\w'
        execute "normal!i" . a:char . "\<Right>"
    else
        execute "normal!i" . a:char  . matching_char[a:char]
    endif
endfunction
```

However, if the user 'accidentally' types in the matching paren at the end, I want it to ignore that so it doesn't double-insert the `)` character. here is an example from how TextMate does it: https://gyazo.com/6766b45bd10f2f80bdf38885d6b33aed. I'd prefer to do this within a function and not use something like `UltiSnips`. How could this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got this in my vimrc:

```
" auto close with matching bracket
inoremap { {}<c-g>U<left>

" if between 2 brackets: "enter" to start inserting between them                                                             
inoremap <expr> <cr> getline('.')[col('.')-2:col('.')-1]=='{}' ? '<cr><esc>O' : '<cr>'

" If on a closing bracket: trying to reclose just skips the character
inoremap <expr> } getline('.')[col('.')-1]=='}' ? '<c-g>U<right>' : '}'
```

A variation for parenthesis would be:

```
inoremap ( ()<c-g>U<left>
inoremap <expr> ) getline('.')[col('.')-1]==')' ? '<c-g>U<right>' : ')'
```